# Verify if user is logged in or not, issues using Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am attempting to verify if a user is logged in or not, and if not sending them to a log in page.  I am using the log in page template from Android Dev. and trying to use an Intent to send either a Boolean or a value ( 1 for logged in 0 for not).  Here is the part of the code in LoginActivity with the Intent:

```
for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
 final boolean logged_in = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
            intent.putExtra("log", logged_in); 
            startActivity(intent);
            }
```

here I am trying as a Boolean and I am getting the error Unreachable code for the line with final boolean Logged_in = true.  When I try as an int

```
int logged_in =1;
```

I get the same error.  All the questions asked on SO state that I needed to use the current class, LoginActivity.this, instead of just this.  When I did use just this, I got another error entirely.
How do I send a value to my MainActivity class to show whether they are logged in or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
```

return ends the method routine so everything after is not reachable.

Comment: DUH!!!  guess that was a total NOOB mistake.  Thanks by adding in an if statement before the return I solved the problem with that at least.